# Default size of integer in Rails tables (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, primary-key

When I run

```
rails g model StripeCustomer user_id:integer customer_id:integer
annotate
```

I got

```
# == Schema Information
# Table name: stripe_customers
#  id          :integer(4)      not null, primary key
#  user_id     :integer(4)
#  customer_id :integer(4)
#  created_at  :datetime
#  updated_at  :datetime
```

Does it mean I can only hold up to 9,999 records only? (I am quite surprise how small a default size for keys is).  How do I change default IDs to be 7 digits in existing tables?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the mysql client's `describe` command really uses the **display width** (see the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)), the schema information in the OP's question is very probably generated by the [annontate_models gem](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models/blob/master/lib/annotate/annotate_models.rb)'s `get_schema_info` method that uses the *limit attribute* of each column. And the limit attribute is the **number of bytes for :binary and :integer columns** (see the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column)).

The method reads (see how the last line adds the limit):

```
def get_schema_info(klass, header, options = {})
  info = "# #{header}\n#\n"
  info << "# Table name: #{klass.table_name}\n#\n"

  max_size = klass.column_names.collect{|name| name.size}.max + 1
  klass.columns.each do |col|
    attrs = []
    attrs << "default(#{quote(col.default)})" unless col.default.nil?
    attrs << "not null" unless col.null
    attrs << "primary key" if col.name == klass.primary_key

    col_type = col.type.to_s
    if col_type == "decimal"
      col_type << "(#{col.precision}, #{col.scale})"
    else
      col_type << "(#{col.limit})" if col.limit
    end

    #...        
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails actually means 4 bytes here, i.e. the standard mysql integer type (see the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column))